# Large number stored as vector more efficiently

Tags: c, arrays, vector, numbers

In my current implementation, I'm initializing char vectors with random numbers representing very large numbers that are more than 20.000 digits. Then I multiply and do operations with these vectors.

I don't know how to initialize them with (for example) base 2^64, so that I can avoid doing the operations digit by digit. I also need to return the numbers to base-10 to the way it was originally represented.

Here's the current implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int seed;

int newrandom() {
  seed = (214013*seed+2531011);
  return (seed>>13);
}


void LongNumInit( char *L, unsigned N )
{
  for ( int i=0; i< N; i++ ) 
  {
    L[i] = newrandom() % 10;
  }
}

void PrintNumber( char *L, unsigned N, char *Name )
{
  printf("%s:", Name);
  for ( int i=N; i>0; i-- ) 
  {
    printf("%d", L[i-1]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}


void ValueSet( char *L, unsigned N, char digit )
{
  for ( int i=0; i< N; i++ ) 
  {
    L[i] = digit;
  }
}


void CPNumber( char *Vin, char *Vout, unsigned N )
{
  for ( int i=0; i< N; i++ ) 
  {
    Vout[i] = Vin[i];
  }
}

char Add( char *Vin1, char *Vin2, char *Vout, unsigned N )
{
  char CARRY = 0;
  for ( int i=0; i< N; i++ ) 
  {
    char R = Vin1[i] + Vin2[i] + CARRY;
    if ( R <= 9 )
    {
      Vout[i] = R; CARRY = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      Vout[i] = R-10; CARRY = 1;
    }
  }
  return CARRY;
}


char DigitAddition( char *V, char digit, unsigned N )
{
  int i=0;
  char R = V[0] + digit;
  if (R < 10)
  {
    V[0] = R; return 0;
  }

  V[0] = R-10;
  char CARRY = 1;
  i = 1;
  while ( CARRY && i < N ) 
  {
    if ( V[i] < 9 )
    {
      V[i] = V[i] + 1; CARRY = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
      V[i] = 0; i++;
    }
  }
  return CARRY;
}


char AddInHorizontal( char *Vin, char *Vout, unsigned N )
{
  char CARRY = 0;
  ValueSet ( Vout, N, 0 );
  for ( int i=0; i< N; i++ ) 
  {
    DigitAddition ( Vout, Vin[i], N );
  }
  return 0;
}

char MultiplyConst( char *V, unsigned N, char digit )
{
  char CARRY = 0;
  for ( int i=0; i< N; i++ ) 
  {
    char R = V[i] * digit + CARRY;
    CARRY = R / 10;
    R = R - CARRY*10;
    V[i] = R;
  }
  return CARRY; // may be from 0 to 9
}

void Mult( char *Vin1, char *Vin2, char *VoutH, char *VoutL,  unsigned N )
{ 

  unsigned char *TEMP= (unsigned char*) malloc( 2*N*sizeof(unsigned char) );
  unsigned char *RES = (unsigned char*) malloc( 2*N*sizeof(unsigned char) );

  ValueSet  ( RES, 2*N, 0 );    // Set RES to 0

  for ( int i=0; i<N; i++ ) 
  { 
    ValueSet  ( TEMP, 2*N, 0 );            
    CPNumber ( Vin1, TEMP+i, N );         
    MultiplyConst( TEMP, 2*N, Vin2[i] );
    Add ( TEMP, RES, RES, 2*N ); // TEMP + RES -> RES
  }

  CPNumber ( RES,   VoutL, N ); 
  CPNumber ( RES+N, VoutH, N ); 
}


int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i, sum1, sum2, sum3, N=10000;

  seed = 12345;

  if (argc>1) { N    = atoi(argv[1]); }
  if (argc>2) { Rep  = atoi(argv[2]); }

  unsigned char *V1= (unsigned char*) malloc( N*sizeof(unsigned char) );
  unsigned char *V2= (unsigned char*) malloc( N*sizeof(unsigned char) );
  unsigned char *V3= (unsigned char*) malloc( N*sizeof(unsigned char) );
  unsigned char *V4= (unsigned char*) malloc( N*sizeof(unsigned char) );

  LongNumInit ( V1, N );
  LongNumInit ( V2, N );
  LongNumInit ( V3, N );

  Add ( V1, V2, V4, N );
  Mult ( V3, V4, V2, V1, N );
  AddInHorizontal ( V1, V2, N );
  DigitAddition ( V3, V2[0], N );

  PrintNumber( V1, 32, "V1" );
  PrintNumber( V2, 32, "V2" );
  PrintNumber( V3, 32, "V3" );
  PrintNumber( V4, 32, "V4" );

  free(V1);
  free(V2);
  free(V3);
  free(V4);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you please post an example that illustrates the question/problem, not the whole code base?

Comment: Note: `Mult()` does not free what it allocates.

Comment: "I don't know how to initialize them with for example a base 2^64 to make operations don't be digit by digit. " --> recommend 2^32 instead, else your multiplication is going to be hard to implement..

Comment: This is not even a question. This is more like *"this is my whole program, please fix it"*.  You need to write a minimal program that reflects your question. If you are more specific about your problem,then it may even turn out, that you are best served by a bignum library (google for "c library for big numbers").